# cassandra is giving timeout exception in pentaho kettle

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, kettle, cql3, connection-timeout

i am using cassandra nosql database for transformation in pentaho data integration.

At the time of manually checking the connection it will connect but while executing the transformation it is giving me timeout exception..

i increased the **"request_timeout"** but problem is still their. and as per my knowledge data in the cassandra database is increasing then only facing such problems.

so is it some problem with PDI tool or because of cassandra database it-self?

And how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. I use Pentaho to fetch data from Cassandra and my tables are growing everyday, as expected. This problem is caused by the huge amount of data. The more data you have, more errors like these will occur. 
I have a table with 200,000 registers, and when I execute the job I get TimeoutException using 190,000 as limit. When I use 150,000 as limit, there is no error. 
If anybody has any idea to solve this issue, please, post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cassandra.yaml, you need to increase the parameter **read_request_timeout_in_ms** to a higher number like 20000. The default number is 10000, and for selects with a huge limit and 10 or 20 columns, you may expect TimeoutException.

Increasing this value will make cassandra wait more for query completion.

I tried this in my database and it worked.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i got the solution long back just forget to write the answer here.. anyways thanks the same works for me as well..\